# How to clear a Jlist

Tags: java, jlist

I have a combo box, and every time an item is selected, there's a corresponding JList that shows up on the panel, and the JList is populated by a text file.

My problem is that when I select between different items in the combo box, if the previous list has more elements, say 3, and the others only have 2, the third item would stay on the list and never go away unless other lists contain at least the same amount of elements.

The following is my code.

```
JList list = new JList();

Path Aparts = Paths.get(".\src\assets\acurap.txt");

String[] partList = new String[50];

String temp2 = "";

teamComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    if (teamComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Acura")) {
        imageLabel.setIcon(acura);
        populatedAcurap();
    }  
}

void populatedAcurap() {
    InputStream input;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Aparts));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        int i = 0;
        temp2 = reader.readLine();
        while(temp2 != null) {
            partList[i] = temp2;
            list.setListData(partList);
            temp2 = reader.readLine();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only are the indents wrong, you aren't following the java coding conventions either. You can read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style about it.

Comment: Set the lists model to a new empty model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read method is all over the place...

- You're constantly reading into an pre-existing array, but you never remove anything from it...so it contains old data...
- It's dangerous to read into an array without knowing how many lines you actually need...
- You don't close your resources...

Instead, read each element from the file and add it to a new `ListModel`, once completed, apply the model to the `JList`, for example...

```
void populatedAcurap() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Files.newInputStream(Aparts)))) {
        String temp2 = null;
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        while((temp2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            model.addElement(temp2);
        }
        list.setModel(model);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For more details, have a look at:

- [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I'm new to Java and our teacher didn't really teach us much so we have to learn ourselves.

Comment: Also, I have a button that adds a new entry to the list, but how do i make it show up on the list when i add it? It does add to the txt file but not on the list until i restart the program. I searched for it I guess the right term is to "refresh" it?

Comment: Get a reference to the `ListModel`, `DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();` then add your element to it, `model.addElement(newElement);`...